# Compare string doesnt work with cin

Tags: c++, string

I am working on a trivial problem, but I cant figure it out. The program should put out the part after "simon says" if the beginning of `str1` is "simon says". if i run it like in the following code, it works, but if i enter the string over `cin >> str1;` myself, it doesnt. Does anybody have a tip for me? (and yes, this is a kattis problem)

```
int main()
{
 string str1("simon says write a program");
 //cin >> str1;
 string str2 ("simon says");
 if (str1.compare(0,10,str2,0,10) == 0){
  cout << str1.substr(11,str1.size());
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::getline()` `cin` reads strings word wise.

Comment: `>>` extracts whitespace-separated tokens. This is not the construction you are looking for.

Comment: oh god im so dumb. thank you. i completely forgot that

Comment: You should print str1 after ``cin << str1``, you can see that the string contains only simon.

Comment: I think you have got the answer you are looking for. So why don't you close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because std::cin gets whitespace-separated strings. If you will try to read a string from the standard input using

```
std::cin << str1;
// something here
std::cin << str2;
```

And you will enter "simon says", "simon" will land in the str1 and "says" will go to the str2. To read a whole line you should use

```
std::getline()
```

Answer (score 1):

With using `cin >> str1`, if you print str1 for the sentence "Simon write something", you will see that `str1` has the value "Simon".

To not cut the sentence to the first space, Replace `cin >> str1` by `getline(cin, str1)`